# How to represent hexadecimal number with two digits in linux scripts (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hex

I have a problem.
I must represent each number with exactly 2 digits (i.e. 0F instead of F)

my code looks something like that:
1. read number of ascii chars are in an environment variable (using wc -w)
2. converting this number to hexadecimal (using bc).

How can I make sure the number I'll get after stage 2 will include a leading 0 (if necessary)

Thanks,
Amigal

Comment: Internal representation don't care about leading zeros(or decimal or hexadecimal, it's just a number), skip that, and add it when displaying the data instead; using printf and the %X-modifier

Comment: I am using an ipmi interface. I am controlling blades in slots through the chassis shelf manager. this protocol requires everything to be represented in two digits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run it through `printf`:

```
$ printf "%02s" 0xf
0f
```

If you have the digits of the number only in a variable, say `$NUMBER`, you can concatenate it with the required `0x` prefix directly:

```
$ NUMBER=fea
$ printf "%04x" 0x$NUMBER
0fea
```

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks! I should have tested it prior to posting, apologies. I couldn't delete the answer due to it being accepted, so I edited instead. I believe it works now (I did test).

Answer (score 6):

Skip the conversion part in `bc` and convert the decimal number with the `printf` command:

```
#num=$(... | wc -w)
num=12  # for testing
printf "%02x" $num
0c
```

If you must convert to hexadecimal for other reasons, then use the `0x` prefix to tell `printf` that the number is already hexadecimal:

```
#num=$(... | wc -w | bc ...)
num=c   # as obtained from bc
printf "%02x" 0x$num
0c
```

The `%x` format requests formatting the number as hexadecimal, `%2x` requests padding to width of two characters, and `%02x` specifically requests padding with leading zeros, which is what you want. Refer to the `printf` manual (`man printf` or `info coreutils printf`) for more details on possible format strings.